# Overwriting the content from one MOSS content database to another

Tags: database, sharepoint-2007, import, export, stsadm

We have a content database on our live moss server. It contains one site collection with several sub-sites. I'm using the stsadm export command to produce a cmp file, then moving this to our test server in a different farm.

I then want to import this content into the content database on our test farm, using the import stsadm command results in me being left with all the existing test data as well as the live data. I tried detaching the existing content database from test in central admin and creating a new empty one,to the then run the import against that but the import failed as obviously there's not root site in the empty db.

The aim is to have the data on test look like live, clearing out all the test data.

Can anyone suggest a good approach to this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

can you try backup and restore of site collection using sts adm. We are following this way. So that we can make exact coppy of production (group and permission also) in our dev enviorment.

backup a SharePoint site is –

```
Stsadm –o backup –url <SiteURL> -filename <FileName>
```

And then at a later date you can restore the site using

```
Stsadm –o restore –url <restoretoURL> -filename <filetorestorefrom>
```

If you want more help, pls comment me...